# send email from my android application

Tags: java, android

I have to send email from my android application.

I have to ruh the app means am getting following error on my logcat window:

```
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.internet.ParseException
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.InvoiceOrder$1.onClick(InvoiceOrder.java:91)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824): Caused by: javax.mail.internet.ParseException
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:102)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1291)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2074)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.InvoiceOrder$1.onClick(InvoiceOrder.java:86)
01-09 05:53:12.263: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  ... 11 more
01-09 05:53:14.023: I/Process(824): Sending signal. PID: 824 SIG: 9
```

These is my code:

```
public class InvoiceOrder extends Activity {


              String mGrandTotal;

          @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.invoice);

               Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
                 login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxx");
                    }
                });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veesxxman@mercuxxsxxryminds.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaxxxdsdveni@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
              //  message.setContent("This is your product name : "+
                    //    "Hi Krishna" +"<br></br>This is your price : "+ "Hi veni", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .size(); i++) {

                        String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                    String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                    String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                    String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);

                    message.setContent("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>", total);
              }

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
           }



  });
```

please help me.whats wrong in my code.why am getting above error.please give me some idea to resolve my error.

Comment: what is line no.91. Please share that line

Comment: @user1503665 these is my 91th line:      throw new RuntimeException(e);

Comment: you are facing these problem becoz  you are not setting your content properly.The error occuring bcoz of thses line :  message.setContent("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>", total); Please check thses link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177045/getting-parseexception-on-transport-sendmessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Javadoc, , while you need `text/html`.As your are using [`MimeMessage#setContent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), you need to add `"text/html;charset==utf-8"` at `message.setContent();`

```
message.setContent(someHtmlMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Note that the HTML should not contain the `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`. Gmail will ignore it.

```
message.setContent( "<tr>
                        <td>" + title + "</td>
                        <td>" + qty + "*" + cost+ "</td>
                        <td>" + "=" + total + "</td>
                    </tr>",   "text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: As `MimeMessage#setContent` sets `text/plain` by default so just use these `message.setContent("Hi Krishna"); or try these message.setContent(Hi Krishna)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: i have to send email directly.thats y i have used javamail api.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
  String mailContent = "mailto:" + mailTo + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;

  Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(mailContent));
  startActivity(intent);
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having only one Recipient in the *To* field, so you should use `setRecipient` method and not `setRecipients`.
Try this:

```
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mercy.krishnaxxxdsdveni@gmail.com));
```

Hope this helps!!